# Make a control in GWT

Tags: java

I am new to java an I would like to know weather we would be able to create a new control in GWT. Or is it possible to customize a control in GWT.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read this article? https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomWidgets

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but a pain to develop and debug - and you need to be able to figure out how to debug and support it in older versions of IE.   ...you may be able to use Firebug and similar tools in most browsers, but the whole process seems counter-intuitive to me, especially if you're new to Java.  You'll find yourself thinking "what I want is an  and a  within a  - how do I get GWT to give me that?"

...why not just start (and finish) with HTML & javascript?

With jquery you'll be able to get a simple web app up and running much more quickly than you would in GWT.  Most of Google's web apps don't even use GWT, they use [Closure](https://developers.google.com/closure/) which has a lot of the benefits of Java, but it's pure javascript.

Comment: Hi Nicholas Albion.Thanks for the reply.Is it possible to customize an existing control in GWT.

Comment: You should be able to extend most GWT controls, yes.  ...But why  have you chosen GWT if you don't know java? What languages do you know?